# Branch coverage for cobertura is not getting displaye in sonar

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I'm using Ant to get the code coverage for cobertura.

I got the coverage.xml, when I integrate it with sonar I'm getting only *line* coverage and not *branch* coverage. I'm sure that my report of the code coverage shows both the line and branch coverage.

My configuration:

- Sonar: 3.4.1
- Cobertura: 1.1

My build.xml for sonar target is

```
<target name="sonar" depends="coverage" >  
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
    <property name="sonar.tests" value="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="bin" />  
    <property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="pmd_report.html" />
    <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="cobertura" />
    <property name="sonar.cobertura.reportPath" value="${dir.coverage}/coverage.xml" />

    <sonar:sonar key="com.employee:employeesalary"
                 version="0.1-SNAPSHOT" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" /> 
</target>
```

Comment: Why do you say that branch coverage is missing ? Is it 0% or not available in UI ?
FI Sonar does not directly import the coverage values but only the branch details from the Cobertura report (attributes "branch" and "condition-coverage" of <line>).

Comment: it is not 0%,Branch coverage is not available in UI.But i can see line coverage alone.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the tab "coverage" of a file which has branches and line coverage please ?

Comment: Sorry iam not able to attach the screenshot of my sonar.so i please look in to this link[sonar screenshot] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263730/branch-coverage-is-not-getting-displayed-in-sonar)

Comment: It's not the expected screenshot. I was asking for the source code of a file that has a branch, like http://www.evernote.com/shard/s251/sh/dbd2f24a-7d81-4e23-b965-b6189a6ee624/a85bc36bd8840f31a6cd649e4c599b53